# Leetcode Python Issue

Tags: python, list

While Trying to solve few question from LeetCode I am facing a really weird issue.

> Question 26: Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array
>
> https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/description/

```
Example:

Given nums = [1,1,2],

Your function should return length = 2, with the first two elements of 
nums being 1 and 2 respectively.
It doesn't matter what you leave beyond the new length.
```

In order to code this question I used :

```
class Solution(object):
def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
    nums = list(set(nums))
    return len(nums)
```

> what this code is doing is first converting the list into a set and
>   then back to list, which in turn will remove the Duplicates

But when I am trying to submit this code to the leetcode solution, modified length of nums is returned but when the program is trying to access the nums array it is not updated.

> This is only Happening in Leetcode editor, in my system If I try to print the nums, the modified value is displayed, not sure what is wrong.

[image]

Now the same case is Happening to other question as well, for example:

> Rotate Array
>   https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/92/array/646/
>
> Rotate an array of n elements to the right by k steps.
>
> For example, with n = 7 and k = 3, the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] is rotated to [5,6,7,1,2,3,4].

My solution to this problem is as follows:

```
class Solution(object):
 def rotate(self, nums, k):
    newIndex = k % len(nums)
    nums = nums[newIndex+1:len(nums)] + nums[0:newIndex+1]
    print nums
```

But again I am amazed by the output I am getting back from the submission.

> Note Here in the "Your STDOUT" we can see the list is modified accordingly.
>   [link to the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gXHD.png)

Please let me know if anyone else is facing this issue or anyone knows the solution to this.

Comment: Please view this thread hopefully it will solve your problem
[Sleep/Resume Scripts Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup)

Comment: Please ignore the above comment and answer, I just updated an old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution to this is to use: `nums[:] = nums[newIndex+1:len(nums)] + nums[0:newIndex+1]`.

Doing `nums = nums[newIndex+1:len(nums)] + nums[0:newIndex+1]` simply changes the reference, while `nums[:]` changes the values of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`sudo service network-manager restart`

Answer (score 0):

what was happening in your code is the length you were returning is been used to travel the `nums` in back-end to print the unique values of the `nums` list. So, the requirement off the problem was the length you returned will be traveled from index 0 to the length returned. Hence with returning the length of unique values, we also have to modify the original list i.e., `nums` .
Solution for the 1st link

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        if(len(nums) == 0):
            return 0
        elif len(nums) == 1 :
            return 1
        else:
            l = 1
            for i in range (1,len(nums)):
                if nums[i] != nums[i-1] :
                    #l+=1
                    nums[l] = nums[i]
                    l+=1
            return l
```